# Multiple plugins with the same name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, plugins

I have difficulty finding answer of these errors.

Before seeing these errors, I did it as follows :

1) I did delete Oculus package (for Unity 4)

2) I did import Oculus Package (for Unity 5)

3) Built my unity project for Android OS, but these errors occurred

> Multiple plugins with the same name 'leap' (found at
>   'Assets/Plugins/Leap.dll' and 'Assets/Plugins/x86_64/Leap.dll'). That
>   means one or more plugins are set to be compatible with Editor. Only
>   one plugin at the time can be used by Editor.
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
>
> Found plugins with same names and architectures,
>   Assets/Plugins/libLeap.so () and Assets/Plugins/x86_64/libLeap.so ().
>   Assign different architectures or delete the duplicate.
>   UnityEditor.AndroidPluginImporterExtension:CheckFileCollisions(String)
>   UnityEditorInternal.PluginsHelper:CheckFileCollisions(BuildTarget) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Plugins/PluginsHelper.cs:25)
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
>
> Plugins colliding with each other.
>
> Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/LeapCSharp.dll', expected 64 bit
>   architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was
>   IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386. You must recompile your plugin for 64 bit
>   architecture. Leap.Frame:.ctor() Leap.Frame:.ctor()
>   LeapRecorder:.ctor() HandController:.ctor()
>
> Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/LeapCSharp.dll', expected 64 bit
>   architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was
>   IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386. You must recompile your plugin for 64 bit
>   architecture. Leap.Frame:.ctor() Leap.Frame:.ctor()
>   LeapRecorder:.ctor() HandController:.ctor()

There are Leap.dll & LeapCSharp.dll file in both 'Plugins' and 'x86_64' folder.

How to solve these problem? Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

+) My Unity version is 5.3.5f Pro version.

Comment: Are you using leap motion asset/plugin?

Comment: Go to your project folder and in the search box, type the name of the duplicate dll. See if you get many results.It could be that the location of the dll was changed and you now have two of the same in different places.

Comment: @Programmer Yes, I use leap motion plugin

Comment: @Everts Thanks. I'll try it.